# Python not creating array properly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
A=[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
```

In my code i go trough every array inside of the array and take two values of importance to me like:

```
arr=[A[j][i-1],A[j][i]]
```

And it works fine the first time i do it inside the for cycle, but i do it again to take another values i want i get this output:

```
arr2=[array[A[j][i-1]],array[A[j][i]]]
```

So the second time it saves each element as its own array. The crazy thing is it only happens the second time. I tried putting it before the one that works but still nothing and i don´t think it's a mistake because i copied the exact same code only changing the variable name.

Anybody knows why? Thanks

Example:

```
FP3=[array([ 0.   ,  4.44 ,  9.517, 19.054, 38.525, 71.371, 84.197, 83.273,
        66.427, 62.726, 54.323, 42.741, 26.953, 15.468, 15.468]),
 array([ 0.      , 46.576483, 78.993133, 91.855251, 97.226361, 95.55402 ,
        95.152298, 94.595104, 94.26279 , 89.147579, 89.171261, 83.769474,
        69.903644, 46.475055])]
for j in range(len(FP3)):
    i=0
    while FP3[j][i]<0.6*max(FP3[j]):
        i=i+1
    XD=[DP3[j][i-1],DP3[j][i]]
    YF=[FP3[j][i-1],FP3[j][i]]
    max_value = max(FP3[j])
    indices = np.where(FP3[j] == max_value)[0]
    i=indices
    while FP3[j][i]>0.85*max(FP3[j]):
        i=i+1
    XD=[DP3[j][i-1],DP3[j][i]]
    YF=[FP3[j][i-1],FP3[j][i]]
    Dc=np.interp(0.85*max(FP3[j]), YF, XD)
    Cp1[j] = Dc
    Cp2[j] = 0.85*max_value
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: _The crazy thing is it only happens the second time_ What exactly do you mean "it happens"?  **What** happens?  And what do you mean "the second time"?  The second time of **what**?  If you're talking about a loop, you need to **show us**.

Comment: Sorry, just posted an example, the first time XD will be two elements and the second time it will be two arrays, same with YD

Comment: @Joe A [mre] needs to include complete code (`DP3` is not defined, among others), expected output, and actual output.

Comment: `A` is a list of lists, not an array.  It looks like some the cycle is converting it either to a list of arrays, or even an array of arrays (object dtype).  Keep lists and arrays separate - in your code and in your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the index "indices" was an array dtype 64 to begin with, so in the loop it would mess with the values. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue, make sure you are using the correct variable name arr2 when storing the values.

arr2 = [arr[A[j][i-1]], arr[A[j][i]]]

Please ensure you are using the correct variable names throughout your code to avoid such issues.

Comment: I think my question is not clear enough sorry, i declare it arr2 = [A[j][i-1], A[j][i]] but get an array of arrays as output

Comment: you can use the extend() function to concatenate the values from A[j][i-1] and A[j][i] into the arr2 list. 

arr2 = []
arr = [A[j][i-1], A[j][i]]
arr2.extend(arr)

Comment: Just posted an example, thanks for your help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).